# How can I get Pyplot to recognise a plateau (almost 0 slope) in a curved line plot, then print ydata value of plateau?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a Python program that shows a plot of a descending temperature vs time. Along the descent the temperature remains constant for awhile, almost 0 slope, then continues to decrease. Its this area in the curve when the temperature is constant that I would like the program to automatically detect and show the y value. This value will later be put into an equation. I'm trying to find out how to do this. I've tried and failed, my last attempt was:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
list_of_files=[('logfile.txt', 'temp')]
datalist = [ ( np.loadtxt(filename), label ) for filename, label in list_of_files]
for data, label in datalist:
    plt.plot( data[:0], data[:,1], label=label )
    plt.ginput(n=1, timeout=30, show_clicks=True, mouse_add=1, mouse_pops=3, mouse_stop=2)
    plt.show()
```

I was hoping a mouseclick on the plateau would show and save the y coordinate, just to lead me in the right direction as far as programming. But all this got was a brief red marker when I clicked on the plot. I don't want to have to mouseclick....Thanks, Rico.

Comment: Could you tell us *what have you tried and failed on?*

Comment: I'm new to programming, so what I've tried are parts of programs I found on internet. The closest I came was just to get a red marker to show up for a second when I mouse clicked on the plot, but no coordinates were saved. The program was something like:

Comment: plt.plot ( data[:,0], data[:,1], label=label )    plt.ginput(n=1, timeout=30, show_clicks=True, mouse_add=1, mouse_pops=3, mouse_stop=2)    plt.show()

Comment: Please put that code in the question.  Do you want to programmaticly detect the plateau or have the user click on it and save the location?

Comment: I don't want to have to click. I want program to detect the plateau and automatically show coordinates.

Comment: Have you tried looking for a zero crossing in the derivative or looking for a local minimum in the derivative?

Comment: Maybe you could try a sliding window, evaluate the gradient inside the window, once that is below a threshold you have found your plateau, then average the values inside the window: voila, your temperature value. The window size (and the step size by which the window moves) is very much dependent on your data.

Answer (score 3):

iterate over small chunks of the data, determine the slope of the chunk, return the point that meets your criteria

```
def zero_slope(data, chunksize = 3, max_slope = .001):
    """return the 'first' data point with zero slope

    data --> numpy ndarray - 2d [[x0,y0],[x1,y1],...]
    chunksize --> odd int
    returns numpy ndarray
    """
    midindex = chunksize / 2
    for index in xrange(len(data) - chunksize):
        chunk = data[index : index + chunksize, :]
        # subtract the endpoints of the chunk
        # if not sufficient, maybe use a linear fit
        dx, dy = abs(chunk[0] - chunk[-1])
        print dy, dx, dy / dx
        if 0 <= dy / dx < max_slope:
            return chunk[midindex]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would answer by improving upon by what wwii has answered.

```
def zero_slope(data, chunksize =4, max_slope = .04):
    midindex = chunksize / 2
    is_plateau = np.zeros((data.shape[0]))
    for index in range(midindex, len(data) - midindex):
        chunk = data[index - midindex : index + midindex]
        # subtract the endpoints of the chunk
        # if not sufficient, maybe use a linear fit
        dy_dx = abs(chunk[0] - chunk[-1])/chunksize
        print(dy, dx, dy / dx)
        if (0 <= dy / dx < max_slope):
            is_plateau[index] = 1.0
    return is_plateau
```

is_plateau returns a series wherein 1 represents plateau and 0 represents no plateau. I have played with a number of values of max_slope and a value of 0.04 seems most appropriate.

Comment: Looks like you need to define "dy" and "dx" separately as well -- also, does midindex have to be "chunksize // 2" to be an integer?